# get special value in url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

```
url:http://localhost:51806/fair/PersonPage/personalPages.aspx?idCompany=1338006699#Site/AboutAs

request["idCompany"];
```

this code return `null`

how can get value `idCompany`

EDIT

```
 Request.UrlReferrer.Query
```

this return `?idCompany=1338006699`

this `Request.UrlReferrer.Query.Split('=')[1]` return `1338006699`

but i think this way does not good way

`#Site/AboutAs` is a tab aboutAs in full tab component

Comment: What's special about it? Assuming you're on personalPages.aspx It should work...

Comment: personalPages.aspx worked and return null for request["idComapny"]

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
string id = Page.PreviousPage.Request.QueryString["idComapny"];
```

If no luck then your method of splitting is the best you can achieve, as you're trying to read the query string of the **referrer** page.

One work around though is to store the value in that previous page.

To do this, store the value of `Request["idComapny"]` in the previous page, where it should be available, in Session then you can read the Session value in any other page.

Comment: @ashk sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "is a tab aboutAs" - how is this relevant to the question? Did you try storing the value in the `Session`?